# Troubles with factory method with shared pointers and restricted constructors

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers, factory-pattern

This compiles OK, but gives runtime error on the `b->hello()` call. My intention is to use dynamic type of the b pointer and call `Inherited::hello()` version.

Help :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    static  shared_ptr<Base> factory();
    string hello(){};
    virtual ~Base() {};

protected:
    Base(){};
};


class InheritedA : public Base{
friend class Base;
public:
    string hello() {return "I am iA";}
protected:
    InheritedA() {};
};


shared_ptr<Base> Base::factory() {
    shared_ptr<Base>        ptrB;
    shared_ptr<InheritedA>  ptrA;
    ptrA = shared_ptr<InheritedA>(new InheritedA);

    ptrB = dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(ptrA);

    return ptrB;
};

int main() {

    shared_ptr<Base> b;
    b = Base::factory();


    cout << b->hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's really no need for either the variables nor the cast. Doing e.g. `return shared_ptr<Base>(new InheritedA);` is enough.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings; they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting one very important thing when it comes to polymorphism and overriding base-class functions: The functions must be `virtual`.

Since your function *isn't* `virtual` you call the `Base::hello` function, and since it doesn't return anything you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), leading to the crash you experience.

You can ask the compiler to help you detect such cases by using the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override):

```
class InheritedA : public Base{
friend class Base;
public:
    string hello() override  // Tell the compiler that this function should
                             // override the function from the parent class
    {return "I am iA";}
protected:
    InheritedA() {};
};
```

If you use the `override` specifier the compiler will issue an error if the function is not `virtual`.

Besides marking the base class function `virtual`, you really should either return something, *anything*, from the function, or make it abstract:

```
class Base {
public:
    static  shared_ptr<Base> factory();

    // Make the function a pure abstract function that must be overridden
    virtual string hello() = 0;

    virtual ~Base() {};

protected:
    Base(){};
};
```

Comment: Of course! :-) I have extracted this from a real, much more complicated code and was totally stuck. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously - `virtual` was missing in `Base::hello()` declaration, also `override` after `InheritedA::hello()` .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    static  shared_ptr<Base> factory();
    virtual string hello(){};
    virtual ~Base() {};

protected:
    Base(){};
};


class InheritedA : public Base{
friend class Base;
public:
    string hello() override {return "I am iA";}
protected:
    InheritedA() {};
};


shared_ptr<Base> Base::factory() {
    shared_ptr<Base>        ptrB;
    shared_ptr<InheritedA>  ptrA;
    ptrA = shared_ptr<InheritedA>(new InheritedA);
    //some very complex stuff here
    ptrB = dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(ptrA);

    return ptrB;
};

int main() {

    shared_ptr<Base> b;
    b = Base::factory();


    cout << b->hello();
    return 0;
}
```